# The side measurement of a die manufactured by a company is a random number X that is uniformly distributed between 1 and 1.25 cm.

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, random-variable

Hi i couldn't find anything similar so please help.

The side measurement of a die manufactured by a company is a random number X that is uniformly distributed between 1 and 1.25 cm. (You may assume the die is a perfect cube.)
(a) Determine the distribution function of the volume of the die.
(b) What is the probability that the volume of a randomly selected die manufactured by
this company is greater than 1.424?
Hint: X^3 ≤ y if and only if X ≤ y^(1/3)
, so F(y) = P(X ≤ y^(1/3)).

so the mean would be (1^3)*(1.25^3)/2?
what about the variance? I'm not sure how to do it..

Comment: Why are you asking about the variance?  Could you explain how that would help you answer either of the questions?

Comment: i thought to find the function i need the standard deviation, which can be found from variance

Comment: You should re-examine that misconception, because it may be blocking you from answering (a).  The hint may help you solve (a) as well as (b): after all, the hint practically tells you what the CDF of the volume is.

Comment: the function, if i understand well should be of the form
 f(x) =(1/(√2π σ))*(e^((−1/2) (x−μ)^2/σ^2)

Comment: That has nothing whatsoever to do with this question and will not help you derive an answer.

Comment: This question seems to fall in the `self-study` category as it sounds quite academic. Could you please add the tag to help readers helping you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f_x(x)=4 (1<=x<=1.25) 0 (o.w)$$
$$f_y(y)=f(x(y))\frac{dx}{dy}$$
$$y=x^3$$
$$x=y^{\frac{1}{3}}$$
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{3}*y^{-\frac{2}{3}}$$
$$f_y(y)=\frac{4}{3}*y^{-\frac{2}{3}} for (1 <= y <= 1.25^3) 0 (o.w)$$
$$P(y>1.424)=\int_{1.424}^{1.25^3} f_y(y)*dy$$
$$P(y>1.424)=\int_{1.424}^{1.25^3} \frac{4}{3}*y^{-\frac{2}{3}}*dy$$
$$P(y>1.424)= \frac{4}{3}*3*y^{\frac{1}{3}}|y=1.424..1.25^3$$
$$P(y>1.424)= 4*\left(1.25^{3*\frac{1}{3}}-1.424^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)$$
$$P(y>1.424)= 0.5$$
Of course if you just took the cube root of 1.424 and noticed it was 1.125 (half way between 1.00 and 1.25) you could have said so much essentially from inspection.
To find the mean and variance complete the following integrals:
$$\mu_y=\int_1^{1.25^3}{y*f_y(y)dy}$$
$$\sigma_y^2=\int_1^{1.25^3}{(y-\mu_y)^2*f_y(y)dy}$$

Comment: thanks a lot!! could you explain where the 4 comes from in the beginning though? Aside from that i understand the reasoning

Comment: No problem.  The 4 makes the pdf integrate to 1.  Since the probability is 0 below 1 and 0 above 1.25, it only has non-zero value for a range of 0.25.  1/0.25 = 4.